# Передача содержимого диапазона ячеек из файла excel в форму

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

Пытаюсь понять, каким образом можно реализовать парсинг данных из excel в форму для последующей обработки в php. Передать содержимое всего файла никаких проблем. Однако мне нужно чтобы человек подгружал определенный файл excel со своего ПК и мог выбрать из загруженного файла определенный диапазон значений ячеек, который будет передан в input.

Через phpexcel получается распарсить загруженный файл целиком и получить массив данных, но дальше застрял. Хотелось бы формировать из этого массива аналог таблицы excel, но чтобы из него можно было выбирать диапазоны и они передавались в форму. В js не силен, но видел в сети различные плагины jQuery excel и не знаю как применить в моем случае.

Может кто-то подскажет как подобное реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.